# Is “the winter returned” idiomatic?

Tags: usage, idiomatic-language

Are “winter is back,” “winter returned” and “Christmas returned” idiomatic in English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this [NGram Graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=winter%20is%20back%2Cwinter%20is%20here%20again%2Cwinter%20is%20back%20again%2C%20winter%20is%20here&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwinter%20is%20back%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwinter%20is%20here%20again%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwinter%20is%20back%20again%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwinter%20is%20here%3B%2Cc0) shows, "winter is back [again]" is used, though "winter is here [again]" occurs much more frequently.

Google NGrams seems to show that "winter returned" is common, but all of the instances that I checked relate to a person whose family name is Winter.

"Christmas returned" and "winter returned" are not idiomatic or used.